# Getting www-data mymailaddress@gmail.com in gmail( Postfix, Ubuntu, PHP)

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, smtp, postfix-mta

I am using ec2 instance ubuntu. I have installed Postfix to send mails.

I am able to send mails successfully using the php `mail()` function. But in the receivers mail address I am getting from address as `www-data mymailaddress@gmail.com`

How should I remove that `www-data`? I just want the receiver to see from address as (mymailaddress@gmail.com) and not `www-data`.

For example, when I send the mail, the receiver gets the information as:

```
From: www-data mymailaddress@gmail.com
To: receiversmailaddress@gmail.com
```